# Angular 4 application crashes in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

My **Angular 4** application crashes in **IE11** right at the application load.

Here is the error that I get:

[image]

Here is where the exception link takes me to in the IE's debugger:

[image]

Any ideas why this would be happening?

**IE version:** 11.0.9600.19003

**Angular version:** 4.3.6

Comment: Have you included/installed the polyfills? https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills

Comment: I have now and it works. Thank you @Ludwig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because IE doesn't support "For_of"

Go to polyfill.ts

1. Un-comment all "import" lines under `/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/` and `/** IE10 and IE11 ....*/`
2. `npm install --save classlist.js
   npm install --save web-animations-js`

Ref : [Angular and Internet Explorer](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9)